# activity not getting killed

Tags: android, android-activity

I want my application to execute some stuff and get killed after that.
I am binding to couple of services in my onCreate() and calling finish() after that as below

```
public void onCreate() {
    //some general code
    boolean b1 = bindService(mIntent1, mServiceConnection1, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE); 
    boolean b2 = bindService(mIntent2, mServiceConnection2, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    //some more general code
    finish();
}
```

I have kept my activity invisible by keeping this in activity manifest

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"
```

Now my problem is when I launch this app, it does the stuff I am assigning to it in onServiceConnected() of ServiceConnection1 and ServiceConnection2 perfectly, apart from that it remains there in device. I mean UNTIL I press either back or home button, I cannot do anything on device. It seems it is there in invisible mode.

By the way, in logs, I can see that the onDestroy has been called already.

Could anyone suggest something to remove this need of pressing back or home button?

Comment: Try to add onDestroy method programmatically.  **protected void onDestroy() { ... }**

Comment: Already have this method, getting the logs too from this method.

Comment: hmm i didn't get it, why do you finish()?

Comment: Try that **finish(); return;** Sometimes finish() doesn't cause the onCreate method to return. Add **return;** statement after your finish method. I am waiting your feedback

Comment: Instead of invisible application, is it possible to use a service for this?

Comment: @helleye that's what are services for...

Comment: no, there has to be an activity(with NO UI or interaction), service cannot be kept for some reason

Comment: @pskink yes, but I had to use the same approach with invisible activity because service was not appropriate...

Comment: what's the difference if you startService() in onCreate() and then finish()? it will be exactly the same result

Answer (score 0):

Try this theme in your manifest:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
```